# Essential self-adjointness of differential operators on compact manifolds

Tags: differential-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $L$ be a linear differential operator (with smooth coefficients) on a compact differentiable manifold $M$ (without boundary). Suppose $M$ is endowed with a smooth volume form (actually, a smooth volume density, if one wishes to consider the non orientable case), so that we can speak about the Hilbert space $L^2(M)$. I regard $L$ as being a densely defined operator on $L^2(M)$ with domain $C^\infty(M)$. Assume that $L$ is symmetric. Is it true that $L$ is essentially self-adjoint? If $L$ is elliptic then the answer is yes (one possible proof: the domain of the adjoint $L^*$ is the set of those $f\in L^2(M)$ such that $L(f)$ --- understood in the distributional sense --- is in $L^2(M)$ and $L^*$ is the restriction of the extension of $L$ to distributions. Let $f$ be an eigenvector of $L^*$ with eigenvalue $\pm i$. Then $f$ is a weak solution of $L(f)=\pm if$ and, by elliptic regularity, $f$ is smooth and it is therefore an eigenvector of $L$ with eigenvalue $\pm i$, contradicting the symmetry of $L$).

Naively speaking, absence of essential self-adjointness is related to the existence of several possible "boundary conditions", which do not exist for compact manifolds. So, naively, the result seems plausible. But maybe I'm being too naive.

Edit: The result is false and the counterexample suggested by Terry Tao works. Let $M=S^1=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and $L=\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)\frac{d}{dx}$. The symmetric operator $L$ is not essentially self-adjoint in $C^\infty(S^1)$. A non zero solution of $(L^*+i)\psi=0$ is obtained using Fourier series. Here are the details: set $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$ and $a_{k+2}=\frac{k}{k+2}a_k+\frac{2}{(k+1)(k+2)}a_{k+1}$ for $k\ge0$. It is easily proven by induction that the sequence $a_k$ is $O(k^{-2/3})$ and hence it is square integrable. The function $\psi(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_ke^{ikx}$ is hence in $L^2(S^1)$ and it solves $(L^*+i)\psi=0$ (because it solves $(L+i)\psi=0$ in the distributional sense).

Comment: By the way, the answer is also affirmative if $L$ is first-order. In that case, $L=-i\big(X+\frac12\mathrm{div}(X)\big)$, with $X$ a smooth vector field in $M$. Since $M$ is compact, $X$ is complete and we obtain $L$ as the generator of a one-parameter unitary group $U_t(f)=(f\circ F_t)\sqrt{\det\mathrm{d}F_t}$, which leaves $C^\infty(M)$ invariant. Thus $L$ is essentially self-adjoint on $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: ($F_t$ denotes the flow of $X$).

Comment: Correcting small imprecision of my previous comment: if $L$ is first-order (symmetric) then $L=-i\big(X+\frac12\mathrm{div}(X)\big)+V$, with $V$ the multiplication operator by a smooth real-valued function. Since $V$ is bounded self-adjoint, the conclusion is the same...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess here is that the answer should be negative, because the answer to the corresponding classical problem is negative.  Namely, there exist symmetric differential operators L such that the Hamiltonian flow associated to the symbol is not complete.  For instance, consider a symmetric operator with principal symbol $-\sin(x) \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ on the circle ${\bf R}/2\pi{\bf Z}$; the symbol here is $\sin(x) \xi^2$, leading to the Hamiltonian flow $\dot \xi = \cos(x) \xi^2$, $\dot x = - 2\sin(x) \xi$, which exhibits Ricatti type blowup in finite time along the $x=0$ axis.

This is not quite a rigorous argument, as I haven't actually ruled out the possibility that unitary propagators $e^{itL}$ still somehow exist, but the fact that at least one semiclassical trajectory blows up makes that possibility quite remote, in my view.  (Presumably one can modify the example so that a positive measure set of trajectories blow up, which would be a more convincing piece of evidence towards non self adjointness.)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are talking about (and maybe I don't), when you say "corresponding classical problem" you mean "classical" as in "classical versus quantum", with a quantization rule like replacing $\xi$ with $-i\frac{d}{dx}$ in the classical Hamiltonian? If that's the case, is there a mathematical reason for believing that the two problems (the "classical" and the "quantum") are related or are you just relying on insights coming from physics?

Comment: By the way, if you take $L=\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)\frac{d}{dx}$ (which is the simplest example of a symmetric operator with principal part $\sin(x)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$) then $L$ surely admits one self-adjoint extension (because its coefficients are real functions) and such a self-adjoint extension does generate a unitary propagator $e^{itL}$. I don't know, though, whether $L$ is essentially self-adjoint. Since $L$ is quite simple I maybe able to figure that out "by hand".

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by classical vs. quantum.  Intuition from both physics and microlocal analysis (e.g. Egorov's theorem on pseudodifferential operators) suggests that $e^{itL}$ should approximately propagate in phase space along the Hamiltonian flow of the symbol (i.e. the quantum flow approximates the classical flow).  If the classical flow is incomplete, this suggests (though does not quite prove) that one has quantum incompleteness also.



Comment: It's true that there will be an abstract self-adjoint extension of real differential operators such as $\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) \frac{d}{dx}$ (because the deficiency indices must match), but the flow maps $e^{itL}$ associated to such extensions have no reason to preserve the initial domain of the operator, and thus need not solve the associated PDE in any reasonable sense (e.g. distributional sense).  As such I would consider these abstract propagators to be "unphysical".

Comment: Right. Thanks. Though, thinking a bit more about this, there are very simple examples in which classical trajectories die in finite time, while the quantum problem is complete. Say, one electron in Coulomb potential: several classical trajectories die in finite time with the electron falling into the singularity (say, if the electron starts at rest), while the corresponding quantum Hamiltonian is essentially self-adjoint in $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Comment: True, but in that case only a zero measure set of trajectories blow up.  Looking at the energy curves for $\sin(x) \xi^2$ it seems to me that almost all trajectories will blow up either forwards or backwards in time, so I would still put my money on quantum incompleteness for this system (or some variant thereof, for instance, one could play with raising the power of $\sin(x)$ here).  A model case to play with might be the operators $\frac{d}{dx} x^m \frac{d}{dx}$ on the real line; of course this isn't a compact manifold, but it might still be informative.

Comment: I think that in the Coulomb potential example you have an open set (not a zero measure set) of initial conditions (electrons that start too slow) that end up in the singularity in finite time. In any case, it seems that you are right about the original issue. $L=\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)\frac{d}{dx}$ is not essentially self-adjoint in $C^\infty(S^1)$. Boring computations with Fourier series yield a non zero solution of $(L^*+i)\psi=0$. So you solved the problem. But I should recheck my computations before I assert that more confidently.

Comment: Double checked. $L=\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)\frac{d}{dx}$ is not essentially self-adjoint in $C^\infty(S^1)$. Thanks.

Comment: Let me add another comment to set the record straight: if $L$ is $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)\frac{d}{dx}$ defined in $C^\infty(S^1)$ and $L'$ is one of the several self-adjoint extensions of $L$ then, while the unitary flow $e^{itL'}$ does not preserve $C^\infty(S^1)$ (otherwise $L$ would be essentially self-adjoint), the map $\psi(t)=e^{itL'}\psi(0)$ solves the associated PDE $\frac{d}{dt}\psi=iL\psi$ in a perfectly reasonable sense, because it solves $\frac{d}{dt}\psi=iL'\psi$ and $L'$ is just the restriction to some subspace of $L^2(S^1)$ of the extension of $L$ to distributions.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that, even if the classical dynamics is incomplete (with a large set of trajectories escaping in finite time), the quantum one might well be complete.

For example, consider on $M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x >0 \}$ the Riemannian metric (Grushin metric)

$$ g = dx^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}dy^2 $$

It is not hard to prove that the Laplace-Beltrami $\Delta$ of the above metric, with domain $C^\infty_c(M)$ is essentially self adjoint (see [[2](https://eudml.org/doc/275451)]). Notice that in the above example there is no external potential: the confinement is purely geometrical.

On the other hand, the principal symbol of $\Delta$ is

$$ 2H = p_x^2 + x^2p_y^2 $$

and it can be prolonged smoothly on the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, where it gives origin to a complete dynamic. In this case, essentially *all* trajectories starting at points with $x>0$ cross at some time the singular region $\{x=0\}$ (the only exception are trajectories with $p_y=0$ and $p_x>0$). More importantly, they do so without losing optimality (in the sense that all these trajectories are shortest paths for the Riemannian metric).

This is a particular instance of a more general fact (i.e. quantum completeness) for non-complete Riemannian structures satisfying suitable conditions at the metric boundary, as proved recently in [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01724)].

Let me mention that quantum completeness for two-dimensional almost-Riemannian structures (a class of which the Grushin metric above is part) has been proved originally in [[2](https://eudml.org/doc/275451)], using the normal forms for 2D almost-Riemannian structures.

A conjecture is still open for more singular situations (i.e. non-regular almost-Riemannian structures in the language of [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01724)]).